# Что за инструменты SDL появились в 2012 студии?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++

Скачал express vs 2012.
Дизайн несколько поразил простотой. 
Но главное при создании проекта, С++ появилась новая опция
*"проверка жизненного цикла разработки безопасного ПО (SDL)"*

Вот здесь вот приводится подробное описание

*http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/security/sdl-tools-download.aspx*

Особый интерес представляет запись

**Анализ C/C++ кода ( ключ /analyze в Visual Studio)**

> Средство статического анализа, которое
> проверяет в исходном коде по одной
> фунции и ищет образцы некорректного
> использования кода C/C++, которые
> могут означать ошибки программирования.

Для этого надо в свойствах проекта в самом низу включить анализ кода.(правда компилируется всё это раза в 3-4 дольше)

Первое что бросилось в глаза, это указания на подобные ошибки:

*warning : C6001: Использование неинициализированной памяти "*array_[BYTE:0]".*
Он смог найти ошибки даже в указателях.

```
int * array_ = new int [10];
std::cout << "\narray_=" << array_[5];

void * pointer_;
pointer_ = array_;
std::cout << "\n1=" << ((int *)pointer_)[7];

void * pointer_2;
pointer_2 = pointer_;
std::cout << "\n2=" << ((int *)pointer_2)[7];
```

Я такого в 2010 не помню, это и есть этот самый статический анализ? 
Выглядит очень интересно.

Comment: хм, я верил что анализ кода всегда был в студии, ну хотя я начал пользоваться со 2010 студии, так вот определенно в ней это есть! p.s. он не только "Использование неинициализированной памяти" находит ;)

Comment: В 2010 анализ есть, только он не работает.

на этот код он скажет вот что:


Выполнение анализа кода...
1>  Анализ кода завершен -- ошибок: 0, предупреждений: 0

Comment: @Аsen
Извините, я не понимаю этих шифровок.
Что вы хотите сказать?

Comment: @manking, в чём собственно вопрос?

Comment: Статические анализаторы кода в отличии от сообщений об ошибках компилятора страдают от ложных срабатываний. Таким образом приходится тратить дополнительное время на ручной отсев ненужных сообщений.

Comment: А это что такое 

Двоичный анализатор BinScope?

Средство моделирования угроз SDL?


Banned.h  – заголовочный файл, который содержит все запрещенные API и позволяет любому разработчиков найти их в коде.

Что значит запрещенные api?

Comment: Запрещенные API - это старые варианты стандартных Сишных функций, которые при вызове не проверяют размер буфера, передаваемого в них. Например, сравните функции [strlen][1] с возможностью buffer overrun и ее потенциальную замену - функцию [StringCchLength][2]. Или сравните [sprintf][3] vs [sprintf_s][4].

 [1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78zh94ax.aspx
 [2]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647539.aspx
 [3]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybk95axf.aspx
 [4]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ce3zzk1k.aspx

Comment: Естественно, что простая замена одних функций на другие проблему не решает. Да и новые, "защищенные" версии функций нужно правильно использовать - передавать правильные аргументы и т.д.